# What can I replace "<=" with inside of a function?

Tags: python

I'm playing around with code for school. I'm trying to utilize `<=` inside the `CalCustCost` function within an if statement, but continue to get an error saying that it is not supported. Is there something else I should be trying? Below is part of the code.

```
def GetServiceType ():
    # This function prompts the user for the service type requested
    # Input: none
    # Output: serviceType

    # Prompt the user for type of cleaning needed
    while True:
        serviceType = (input("\nWhat type of cleaning service are you needing? (Please enter one of Windows , Floors , or, Both ): \t  "))
        if (serviceType in ("Windows", "windows", "Floors", "floors", "Both", "both")):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter one of Windows, Floors, or Both")

    return(serviceType)


# GetNumRooms ----------------------------------
def GetNumRooms ():
    # This function prompts the user for the number of rooms needed to be cleaned
    # Input: non
    # Output: numRooms

    # Prompt the user for number of rooms needed to be cleaned
    while True:
        numRooms = int(input("\nHow many rooms do you need cleaned? \t  "))
        if (numRooms > 0):
            break
        if (numRooms < 0):
            print("Please enter a positive number of rooms")

    return(numRooms)


# CalCustCost -----------------------------------
def CalCustCost (serviceType, numRooms):
    # This function calculates all costs for customer
    # Input: serviceType, numRooms
    # Output: windowCleaningCost, floorCleaningCost, totalCost - total customer cost (floors + windows)


    # Initialize Variables, these variables will be used in the overall calculations for costs
    smallCostF = 39.99      #Cost of floor cleaning for 2 rooms or less
    mediumCostF = 29.99     #Cost of floor cleaning for 3/4 rooms
    largeCostF = 24.99      #Cost of floor cleaning for 5 rooms or more
    smallCostW = 19.99      #Cost of window cleaning for 2 rooms or less
    mediumCostW = 14.99     #Cost of window cleaning for 3/4 rooms
    largeCostW = 9.99       #Cost of window cleaning for 5 rooms or more    
    
    # Calculate cost per service
    if (serviceType == "Windows") or (serviceType == "windows"):
        if (0 <= numRooms <= 2):
            windowCleaningCost = smallCostW * numRooms
        elif (2 < numRooms <= 4):
            windowCleaningCost = mediumCostW * numRooms
        else:
            windowCleaningCost = largeCostW * numRooms
        floorCleaningCost = 0
```

I am getting the error under the `CalCustCost` function when calculating the cost per service.

Comment: You've got a lot of code there. But you are missing the full traceback that shows the exact error and the line that failed. Once you know the bad line, you can add a print to see what values are causing the problem. And you can likely trim the code down.

Comment: The code doesn't produce a problem.  It's missing actually *calling* any function, but manually callling `CalCustCost` produces no error.  If it does for you, it may be *how* you are calling it, which isn't provided.  Make sure to write a [mcve] and post the traceback of the error.

Comment: As an aside, parentheses around if statements and return values are not required.

Comment: Be sure you include your _actual_ error message in the question itself. Typically a comparison operator being "not supported" doesn't depend on context (like whether you're "in a function"), but instead depends on the datatypes of the values you're trying to compare (say, trying to compare an integer with a string); the full, original text of the error message will describe those types.

Comment: (and if you're running with a Python interpreter so old that it doesn't support syntax that's valid in modern interpreters, seeing the exact error message would let us identify that that's what's going on).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: in `GetNumRooms()` you don't print the "Please enter a positive..." message if they enter `0`.

Comment: Make sure `numRooms` is a number, not a string.